# what is wrong with this line of SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Batch.NumStud 
FROM Batch 
WHERE CourseID='$courseid'
INNER JOIN Course 
ON Batch.CourseID=Course.CourseID"
```

an error that says  `mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>F:\AppServ\www\anNoECourse.php`

is shown.This code was written to feed in data  to a  google  chart.

Comment: Mr.Watson says: Where and join are in the wrong order... (And take seriously the comment Andy Lester left, SQL injection is harmful)

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: The PHP error says that the problem is not in the SQL, but in the PHP code.

Comment: Please, do not use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed in future versions of PHP. New applications should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) whenever possible, `mysqli` otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You put SQL in *wrong order* (JOIN and WHERE are switched):

```
  SELECT Batch.NumStud 
    FROM Batch INNER JOIN Course 
           ON Batch.CourseID = Course.CourseID
   WHERE Course.CourseID = '$courseid'
```

It seems, that your query can be *simplified* (check your data):

```
  select Batch.NumStud 
    from Batch
   where Batch.CourseID = '$courseid'
```

Comment: While this makes sure that he gets data most of the time, his code will still fail in case the database can not be reached, because he's not handling the result of `mysql_query` correctly (see my reply). This should also be noted prominently!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is a bit more complex. Due to the fact that your SQL is invalid, you're not getting a result set. This case is not handled correctly by your PHP code!

So in addition to correcting your SQL as the others have suggested, please make sure to handle the case where you get no results or your query results in an error correctly in your PHP code!

The second part to your solution is as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if ($result)
{
    while (...)
        ...
}
```

This makes sure that `mysql_query` actually returned a result set and not `false`, which it does in case of errors (due to your invalid SQL code, but also in other cases). So just fixing your SQL is not enough to make your script error proof.

But again, do no longer use the `mysql_....` functions! They are deprecated.